# node.js express 4.11.2 & socket.io getting error ?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

here is my setup
this works fine with express version 4.8.0 and socket.io 1.0.6
and also express 4.8.0 and socket version 1.3.3

so i'm assuming they've changed something in express.

current version of express is 4.11.2
current version of socket.io is 1.3.3

and now i'm getting the error on the client side.

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423775884240-0  net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

i'm using socket.io namespacing

```
var express = require('express'),
website = express(),
http = require('http').Server(website),
io = require('socket.io')(http),
routes = require('./routes'),
path = require('path'),
logger = require('express-logger'),
json = require('express-json'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
methodOverride = require('express-method-override');


website.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
website.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
website.set('view engine', 'ejs');
website.set('socket', io);
website.set('socketId', '1234');
website.use(logger({path: './logs/logfile.txt'}));
website.use(json());
website.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
website.use(methodOverride());
website.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Setup routing
require('./routing')(website);

http.listen(website.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Website ready, listening on port: ' + website.get('port'));
});

module.exports = website;
```

this is on my index page for the connection

```
var socketId = website.get('socketId');
var io = website.get('socket').of('/' + socketId);
```

would anyone be able to tell me where i'm going wrong.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug with socket.io, using namespace will ignore port, or default to port 80.

More info here:

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/pull/803